# Eclipse updates blank in ubuntu vm

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, swt, virtualbox

I'm running Eclipse in an Ubuntu VM and when I go to Help -> Install New Software, the box that displays the updates is blank for any update site.  It seems like it may be a SWT rendering issue with the VirtualBox display drivers, but I'm not sure.  Has anyone else seen this?

- VirtualBox 4.1.16
- Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit

  - Kernel 3.2.0-24
- Virtual Box Guest Additions 4.1.16
- Eclipse 3.7.2

Comment: "blank" in a black-window or noise-filled window that doesn't look right? Or just no content? Programs on Unix systems usually do not update themselves -- in fact, the permissions usually _forbid_ programs to make modifications to themselves -- so perhaps it is just a portion of the program that does not make sense on your platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that one of the configuration files in the workspace .metadata folder was corrupt.